# schema.default=none not working

Tags: titan, gremlin

I set:

```
 schema.default=none
```

at the bottom of titan-cassandra-es.properties and restarted with `bin/titan.sh start`.

Then the following happened:

```
gremlin> g.addVertex(null,[name:"stephen"])
==>v[2560256]
```

Shouldn't it complain that the property key label 'stephen' hasn't been defined?

Comment: did you solved this

Comment: @Akshay I switched to PostgresSQL.